# Why must static access to class be qualified with class name

Tags: java, specifications

Why must I qualify a reference to `class` inside the class that it's defined in? For example:

```
public class Foo {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
}
```

Why can't I just call `LoggerFactory.getLogger(class)` since I'm already in the context of the `Foo` class?

Comment: That's how the language was defined.

Comment: Foo.class is a Class literal (see oracle documentation). Your syntax would make sense but it is not part of the Java language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) defines

> ## 15.8.2. Class Literals
>
> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token `class`.

It wouldn't make the language ambiguous to allow `class` where an expression is expected to allow the syntax you describe, but it would involve overriding the keyword `class` to mean both

1. a kind of declaration
2. a reference to an instance of type `Class`.

The syntax you suggest might allow naming the class of an anonymous class, but `getClass()` would have the same meaning in anonymous classes.

Getting rid of two tokens (the unqualified class name and the `.`) doesn't provide much value, and it could cause confusion inside an inner class.  For example, what is `class` inside a lambda expression?